# Finding a very first Date occurrence in a string

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an interesting task of finding a very first Date value in a Text field. There are no identifiers, sometimes the date would come in various formats such as '01/01/2015', '1/1/2015', 1/1/15', '1/01/15', etc. 
Format will always be Month, Day, Year; however, it could vary from
mm/dd/yyyy, mm/dd/yy, m/dd/yyyy, etc.

**For example:**

> The rain in Spain falls mainly on 01/01/2015 and then it ends between
>   03/02/2015 and 04/01/2015.

I want to capture "01/01/2015", because it is a very first date occurrence in the string.

Trying to figure out the easiest way to extract the very first date occurrence, but no such luck as of yet.
Any suggestions?

Tks!

Comment: by very first date do you mean the minimum date?

Comment: will the format of the dates always be mm/dd/yyyy or you can have other formats too?

Comment: It will always be Month/Day/Year; however, some single digit values appear without zeros. For example: 1/10/2015 or 1/2/15 or 10/2/2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok This will work somewhat or at least its a good place to start:

you can find out more about string functions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms181984.aspx)

```
DECLARE @ST VARCHAR(MAX) =  'The rain in Spain falls mainly on  1/1/2015 and then it ends between 03/02/2015 and 04/01/2015'

SELECT  SUBSTRING(@ST,PATINDEX ( '%[0-9]%/%[0-9]/%[0-9]%' , @ST ),PATINDEX ('%[A-Z]%', SUBSTRING(@ST,PATINDEX ( '%[0-9]%/%[0-9]/%[0-9]%' , @ST ),LEN(@ST)))-1)
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks.
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. I will try to figure out the issue in the parsing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using sql, you can use a LIKE to identify that there is a date in a string:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Value LIKE '% %/%/% %'
```

Each "%" matches one or more character. If you want to extract the first date, it might be possible with a case statement. See: [TSQL CASE with if comparison in SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231353/tsql-case-with-if-comparison-in-select-statement)

Comment: and the answer below looks even better.